# How to force Slack to apply markdown within a word?

Tags: slack, markdown

Slack has "recently" introduced its a bit annoying WYSIWYG "message composer" which breaks the message formatting with the inline markdown. Fortunately there is now also option called "format messages with markup" which kind of reverts this feature back to normal, but...

I would like to know, how to force this inline markdown interpreter to work also in the middle of words. For example, how to achieve these:

> par<s>tiallys</s>trike
>
> `connect`ed

Apparently, the following:

> `par~tiallys~trike`
>
> `` `connect`ed ``

do not work. There must be a separator before/after `~` or `` ` ``, but if space is used, it's no more a single word :-( Is there any "invisible" (and simply reachable) character Slack would accept as a separator which we could use for this purpose?